# No "Remove Widget" or "Replace widget with its children" in Android Studio Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, widget

I have the latest plugin version of Flutter v49.0.2 and Android Studio v4.0.1 still, I am missing this feature of removing the widget from the widget tree. Does somebody else is having the same problem? Need help with this thing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just want to remove the widget for quick coding. Manually removing will lead to bugs and errors and also managing brackets and parenthesis will be time-consuming.

Comment: tried other widgets, like `Container` / `Expanded` / `Padding` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `CustomScrollView` with several children in the `slivers` you wont be able to auto remove the `CustomScrollView`. The remove widget only works for a parent with one child.